# No OpenGL or Nvidia in the docker

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I tried to install the latest Autoware.auto in Ubuntu 18.04. I have Nvidia drivers and docker installed, I can run nvidia-smi and glxgears in the host but not in the ADE. Rviz2 cannot start due to wrong OpenGL context. Can anyone tell me how to add the OpenGL and Nvidia support into the docker images? Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/354751/no-opengl-or-nvidia-in-the-docker/) by [Mike_Auto](https://answers.ros.org/users/55735/mike_auto/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2020-06-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

By default, we now disable GPU passthrough support in the standard `.aderc` file. This is because if you have an Nvidia GPU but don't have `nvidia-container-toolkit` installed, you will get errors as well. To use Nvidia GPU passthrough, you'll need to install `nvidia-container-toolkit` using [the instructions here](https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-docker/blob/master/README.md#ubuntu-160418042004-debian-jessiestretchbuster). After that, modify your `.aderc` file and remove the line `export ADE_DISABLE_NVIDIA_DOCKER=true` to re-enable Nvidia GPU passthrough.

**Note:** The `.aderc-lgsvl` file does not have this line because LGSVL requires an Nvidia GPU with GPU passthrough enabled.

---

Originally posted by [Josh Whitley](https://answers.ros.org/users/4390/josh-whitley/) with karma: 1766 on 2020-06-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Josh Whitley](https://answers.ros.org/users/4390/josh-whitley/) on 2020-06-16**:
There is also an ongoing discussion about this in [this issue](https://gitlab.com/autowarefoundation/autoware.auto/AutowareAuto/-/issues/502).

**Comment by [LennartL](https://answers.ros.org/users/57733/lennartl/) on 2020-08-18**:
This helped me while following the lgsvl tutorial for Autoware.Auto: https://www.lgsvlsimulator.com/docs/autoware-auto-instructions/#run-simulator-alongside-autoware-auto
Thank you very much.